# Computer boots to screen with text listing devices but stops there

Tags: windows-xp, boot, data-recovery, desktop-computer

I've got an issue with an old computer running windows XP(yep, when I say old I mean *old!*)

I can't find the problem on google as I'm not really sure what to call it.  Most of my results brought up black screens issues etc.  However I've seen this issue on at least one other computer so I'm sure it can't be that rare.

Please see the image below.

[image: Click here to view image of the computer screen]

The computer will boot to this screen every time.  I've tried putting a bootable recovery usb in it (and yes I know the usb works because it's worked on other pc's) and checking the boot order, also selecting the usb from boot, but whatever I do it shows this screen.  Also tried pulling the CMOS battery and replacing but that doesn't do anything.

Does anyone know what causes this issue?  If I just knew why it was doing this I might be able to get it fixed but I don't even know if it's software or hardware related.  Until a few days ago, this pc booted XP without a problem, and this happened.  If anyone knows how to fix this issue or can give me some links to solutions how to fix this that would be even better!

Comment: hard drive failure?  according to that screen there's no hard drive installed at all.  (that would be normal for certain kinds of hard drive failure.)  have you set boot order so that USB is tried before CD/DVD?

Comment: How can you tell that - is that because it says "Diskette Drive A : None" - if there was a hard disc connected, is this where it would say it was connected?  or what are you looking at?   :) sorry if it's a dumb question!

Comment: `primary master` and `primary slave` -- this looks to be an old IDE system, that's where drives attached to the mainboard's IDE interfaces would be shown.  (there are 2 IDE controllers listed in the device list, so it's possible an offboard IDE controller might be in use that wouldn't be shown on this screen.)  ("diskette drive" refers to a floppy drive.)

Comment: Got it thanks, will check the drive again and ensure plugged in and bootable.

Comment: Right.  It looks as though no power may be getting to the drive - which is weird because the CD drive is working, and the hard drive is powered off the same cable as the CD drive.  I'm guessing that the cable may have broken at some point or there's an hard drive internal issue related to power.